# "Certainly" and "Of course": what is the difference?

Tags: differences, adverbs

Is there any difference in expressing consent and assurance using adverbs "certainly" or "of course"? What would be more appropriate one in everyday conversation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to expressing consent and assurance, I'd say the difference certainly isn't very big. :-) When faced with a question like

> Can I have some more coffee?

..."Of course" would probably be a more typical reply. But there's nothing wrong with "Certainly" either (although it might sound a little more formal).

Oh, as you mention the context is *everyday conversation*, you should also consider something like:

> Yeah, sure!

:-)

Comment: Thanks, especially for your remark about using "sure" in everyday conversation, +1

Answer (score 2):

`Certainly` is used for emphasizing that something is definitely true or will definitely happen:

> I certainly hope you’re right.
>   There certainly wasn’t any point in doing it
>   now.

In this fashion, `certainly` is slightly different from `of course`.

When used for expressing agreement or giving permission in daily conversations, `certainly` and `of course` have the same meaning:

> -We’d like you to explain your proposal to us in greater detail.
>   -Certainly. / Of course.